# How to make a grid of ellipses with subdivisions

Tags: javascript, grid, p5.js

I have created a circle with subdivisions (function CircleSubDivs) in p5.js and now want to generate a grid filled with those. Ideally the ellipse would also be disproportionate if the width and height of a tile is not the same, or if the amount of tiles were to be controlled by the mouse position the ellipse would move flexibly.
[This was my inspiration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddlBk.jpg)

This is my code so far:

```js
// let colors = [
//  "#F48668 ",
//  "#5D2E8C",
//  "#F7F7F7"
// ];

function CircleSubDivs(x, y, size) {
  let amount = 13;
  let r = 360 / amount;

  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

      fill(random(255));

      let s = map(j, 0, 8, width, 100);

      arc(width / 2, height / 2, s, s, radians(r * i), radians(r * (i + 1)));

    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
  background("#0F0F0F");
  noStroke();

  let tilesX = 3;
  let tilesY = 2;
  let tileW = width / tilesX;
  let tileH = height / tilesY;

  for (let x = 0; x < tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tilesY; y++) {
      CircleSubDivs(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

As you can see I have created a grid and tried to store my function for the ellipse with divisions in there, but it just shows me one single ellipse when I run it. I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: You never use `x`, `y` and `size` in `CircleSubDivs(x, y, size)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters to your function are unused, so the function does the same thing every time.

You might try something like:

```js
function drawSubdividedCircle(x, y, size, segments=13, layers=10) {
  const r = 360 / segments;

  for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < layers; j++) {
      fill(random(255));
      const s = map(j, 0, layers, size, 0);
      arc(
        x + size / 2,
        y + size / 2,
        s,
        s,
        radians(r * i),
        radians(r * (i + 1))
      );
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
  background("#0F0F0F");
  noStroke();
  const tilesX = 3;
  const tilesY = 2;
  const tileSize = width / tilesX;

  for (let x = 0; x < tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tilesY; y++) {
      drawSubdividedCircle(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```